# Form to assign value from variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get my form to assign values to text fields. I have a helper file that defines current_user. I want the text_field :name to be the current_user.name.

```
<%= form_for @message, :url => contact_path do |form| %>
<%= form.text_field :name = current_user.name %>
<%= form.text_field :email = current_user.email %>
...
```

I have tried #{name}, params, how do you assign this value?

Comment: = f.name, value: current_user.name

Comment: since the value is going to be fixed(in this case the name,) why are you specifying a text field at all. just display the current user's name as static text. that would be better approach.

Comment: @prasad.surase sure, how would you do this so the form gets the value?

Comment: you dont submit the name(static data) at all. assign them explicitly in the controller action. ie. if you have actions 'new' & 'create', you display the name as static text in new.html.haml and in the 'create' action you explicitly specify that '@obj.name = current_user.name'.

Comment: if you use f.name, value: current_user.name and that textfield should not be manipulated by user, then my approach is better. if you want the field to be manipulated but need to specify some default value then using 'value: current_user.name' is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do that in your controller

for example: (See 3rd line)

```
def update
  @message = Message.find(params[:id])
  @message.name = current_user.name ## HERE
  @message.update_attributes
end
```

Unless you mean you want it to be the default value when the page renders, in which case:

```
<%= form.text_field :name, value: current_user.name %>
```

or if you like

```
<%= form.text_field :name, placeholder: current_user.name %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `value` option to the `text_field` helper as:

```
<%= form_for @message, :url => contact_path do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :name, value: current_user.name %>
  <%= form.text_field :email, value: current_user.email %>
  ...
```